CMake+Conan: How to overwrite compiler directive for dependency?
How can I unset a compiler directive defined by Conan's CMake integration?
Background:
I port a C++ project with a makefile-based build system to CMake (3.29) and Conan (2.2.2). This project depends on the spdlog library that I import in my conanfile.txt:
[requires]
...
spdlog/1.13.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain

[layout]
cmake_layout

Following the Conan tutorial, I imported dependencies and generated CMake integration artifacts via
conan install . --output-folder=conan --build=missing

I then configured my project via
cmake -B out -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan/build/Release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake -S .

Eventually, I ran
cmake --build . -v

from the build folder.
However, my build fails because Conan configures spdlog to use an external formatting library (fmt). To do so, it sets the compiler directive -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL, in one of the cmake files it generates. To fix my build I need to unset/overwrite this compiler directive. How?
Attempts
What I tried so far is
target_compile_options(${NAME}
  PRIVATE 
  -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL=OFF)

However, this simply adds -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL=OFF after -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL and thus does not fix my issue.

However, my build fails because Conan configures spdlog to use an external formatting library It is not clear what is the issue with that. Do you want spdlog to use the std format? The package has an option called use_std_fmt that can be used to select it. Define spdlog*:use_std_fmt=True in your profile, command line or conanfile.

This might be better responded as a github issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

@drodri The spdlog library has 3 different ways of handling log string formatting: 1. use the external fmt library, the default in the conan package 2. use std::format, which may be activated by setting use_std_fmt to true in the conan package 3. use built-in minimal formatting support, not dependent on any external library, which seems not to have a corresponding conan package option. The project in question has been originally developed using the third option. It compiles neither with 1. nor with 2. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to activate 3.

As per @drodri 's suggestion I asked this question in the Conan github repo: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/16004

Answering my own question: I can patch the file generated by Conan that defines -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL, using Conan's conan.tools.files.replace_in_file() function in my Conanfile's generate() method. Which buys me nothing since the spdlog packaged has been installed with -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL, causing the bundled copy of fmt - that I need for my code to compile - to be discarded. This approach gets me nowhere.
